# Mobile phone and Safari browser do not navigate to my website, search instead

Tags: macos, browser, android, domain, safari

I recently registered a domain name at the root domain `.science`.
I put up a website, and can navigate to it fine.

But if I type `mydomain.science` into my phone (android), another phone (ios), or safari (on a mac) it does not navigate me to my site, but instead does a google search.
Although, on my phone I have been able to get to my website by going to `http://mydomain.science`

Could this be a mistake on my part (like not setting up the DNS records correctly) or is it just that the browsers don't recognize the new top level domain?

Comment: Yes;  This has to do with your DNS records.

Comment: What exactly? Do I have to add a `mobile.` subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

So this seems to be a persistent problem with new top level domains. http://domainincite.com/11673-apple-google-and-microsoft-still-dont-understand-new-tlds

Safari supposedly fixed this with `7.0.3`